# Как сделать так, чтобы Sequelize(Mysql) при созданий пользователя копировал его id в другую колонку user_id?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
const User = sequelize.define("users" , {
    username: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    user_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        defaultValue:???????????
    }
});
```

Comment: DEFAULT VALUE в MySQL не может ссылаться на автоинкрементное поле. И фреймворк ничего в этом изменить не сможет.

Comment: а есть ли какой то способ иной без defaulValue?

Comment: Триггер тоже ничем не поможет. Так что решайте проблему на уровне приложения. Или уходите от запросов к хранимым процедурам - там можно реализовать практически любую логику.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем делать 2 одинаковых поля?
Можно использовать только userId.
Установите:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
const User = sequelize.define("users" , {
    username: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    user_id: {
      primaryKey: true,
      type: UUID,
      defaultValue: UUIDV4,
    }
});
```

Так поле id не будет автоматически генерироваться. Я верно понял вашу проблему?